# Pass object and function to javascript class and return onSuccess and onError

Tags: javascript, html

I try to define a javascript class that will receive an object as a parameter and some self define callback functions like `onSucess` and `onError` and use those functions to return a response to the user.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
class User {

    constructor(param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    static create(param) {
        return new User(param);
    }

    onSuccess() {

    }

    onError() {

    }

    showForm() {

    }
}
```

And this is how I want to invoke the class

```
let user = User.create({
    name: 'name_here', 
    email: 'user@email.com',
    age: 37,
    onSuccess: (response) => {

    },
    onError: (error) => {

    }
})
user.showForm()
```

My question now is how can I invoke a User class like this

```
let user = User.create({
    name: 'name_here', 
    email: 'user@email.com',
    age: 37,
    onSuccess: (response) => {

    },
    onError: (error) => {

    }
})
user.showForm()
```

Though that may not be the proper way to define the class and its functions, but that how I want the class to be called.

I will appreciate any corrections or suggestions.

Thanks.

Imagine the class is like this:

```
class User {
    constructor(param) {
        Object.assign(this, param);
    }

    static create(param) {
        return new User(param);
    }

}
```

and I want to invoke the User class like this:

```
let user = User.create({
    name: 'name_here',
    email: 'user@email.com',
    age: 37,
    onSuccess: (response) => {
        alert("onSuccess");
    },
    onError: (error) => {
        alert("error");
    }
})
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Have updated the description @decpk

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: It not working the way I want @code

Comment: What's not working? What's the specific problem?

Comment: Don't mind the way the class was structure, that may not the right way of what I need but look at how I want the class to be call @code

Comment: @adedeji-sikiru-da-webcoded you have to assign `this` to `param` to assign all prop and methods of `User`. So use `Object.assign(this, param).`

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `onSuccess`, and `onError` in the params as callback like so:

```js
class User {
  constructor(param) {
    this.param = param;
  }

  static create({onSuccess, onError, ...param}) {
      try {
        const newUser = new User(param);
        onSuccess(newUser);
      } catch (e) {
          onError(e)
      }
  }

  showForm() {}
}

let user = User.create({
    name: 'name_here', 
    email: 'user@email.com',
    age: 37,
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      console.log("Success!");
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log("Error!");
    }
})
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want.You just save my day